# React Redux - Variable into initialstate and how to create CASE dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to give more flexibility to my reducer without adding different initalstates and
cases.

I try to explain:

```
import {
  FETCH_DB,
  FETCH_CAT,
} from "../types"


// put a variable here:
const initalState = {
  db: [],
  categories: [], // create a dynamic state i.e. categories.VARIABLE 
}

export default (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DB:
      return {
        ...state,
        db: action.payload,
        current: null,
        loading: false,
      }
    case FETCH_CAT:
          
          VARIABLE HERE
          
      return {
        ...state,
        categories[VARIABLE]: action.payload, // syntax with [] doesn't work
        loading: false,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

My aim is to pass a variable through out a component so I can have `categories.VAR` as many as I want.

Does someone know if is possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
case FETCH_CAT:

  return {
    ...state,
    categories: {
      ...state.categories,
      [variable]: action.payload
    },
    loading: false
  }
```

Comment: thanks but it's the first thing I tried but doesn't work. Maybe is not the syntax

Comment: @MarcoDisco I know it's already been answered, but this should work.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it may be your solution

```js
case FETCH_CAT:

  const newState = {
    ...state,
    loading: false
  }
  newState.categories[variable] = action.payload

  return newState
```

Comment: hi! thanks your solution looks like working. I just have to find how to extract the data.